# Why didn't I receive the Strunk & White badge?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, badges

I thought the Strunk & White badge is awarded for 80 edits. So far I have more than 80 edits, but I still don't have that badge. When I paid attention on this issue I see the edits I count on my activities tab are actually claimed as Suggested Edit.

Is this why I didn't get that badge? If so how will I make real edits to be counted as for this badge.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/badge-progress-reports

Comment: I see, the edits I did on my posts don't count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you can see that you have edited 73 posts

> [image]

This is the reason that still you haven't receive `Strunk & White` badge.

You can check it your self by following steps,

- Click on the "User" button on Stackoverflow site.
- Click on "editor" tab.
- Click on "all" tab.
- Type your name in Textbox.
- Done.

You can see in your profile's [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1469980/tolga-evcimen?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) tab that you have edited 85 post. I assume few of the posts ( around 12 ) were removed ( deleted ) later on. These removed posts are not counted for `Strunk & White` badge.

Comment: I guess it's a shame being not able to see those statistics on your own profile. Thanks for the workaround though.

Comment: The Editors tab counts are **not** indicative of badge progress however. The edit total there can easily be higher from the actual count of edits that count towards the badge.