# Why haven't I received the Strunk & White badge?

Tags: support, edits, badges

I did a bunch of edits yesterday, and according to SO I have completed 103 edits.

[See my editor information](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all&search=dan)

Strunk & White is supposed to be rewarded after editing 80 posts.  Is there a time delay on this? Thanks

FYI this is not a duplicate of [Why didn't I receive the Strunk & White badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253691/strunk-white-badge-didnt-received), in that question OP does not have more than 80 edits.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to have edited 80 *unique* posts that have not since been deleted, none of which can be your own. Tag-only edits also don't count. The editor tab does not make those distinctions, so the count there cannot be used as a guide.

See [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188732#188732); from the `Strunk & White` entry:

> - Perform a total of 80 edits between questions, answers and tag wikis
>
> [...]
>
> - Edits on deleted posts do not count
> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to CW posts **do** count
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> - Tag wiki edits **do** count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges **do** count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

Also, the badge is not handed out the moment your 80th edit has been accepted, badges are handed out with a batch process. It can take a few hours before you are awarded the badge.

You can see your progress by visiting the [suggested edits statistics page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats), then hover over the progress bar at the top right:

[image: progress bar]

to expand it to reveal a set of three more:

[image: progress bar expanded]

For the Strunk & White silver badge, look at the Copy Editor progress bar; you'll receive it when that indicates you've edited 80 posts.

Comment: Ahhh...so tag changes only do not count.  That explains my situation, thanks!  FYI Strunk & White is 80, Copy Editor is 500 (minor typo in your answer). Thanks again

Comment: @Dan: The *progress bar* shows progress towards Copy Editor always, that's why you need to look for the '80' count; the criteria are the same.

Comment: Got it, I was specifically referring to "Perform a total of 500 edits".  Great answer, very helpful, thanks!

Comment: @Dan: the text had to come from the *Copy Editor* badge section, as the criteria *other than the edit count* are the same.

Comment: @Dan: edited to make it clearer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  I don't see any way to see our "stats". How did you get to the last image?

Comment: @Pacerier: it follows from the image before; you mouse over the green bar visible in any of the queue views. I provided a link to the stats page of the *suggested edits* review queue.

Answer (score 4):

Additionally, I found this tool which enables you to check on how many edits you have made towards earning the "Editor", "Strunk & White", and "Copy Editor" badges

#### [Link here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/28666/how-many-edits-have-i-made-and-how-much-more-until-i-earn-the-badges)