# Why does 79 equal 85?

Tags: bug

I was looking at my sweet new [activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1305516/david-grinberg?tab=summary) when I noticed something odd. My next badge is listed as Strunk & White, which you earn for editing 80 posts. I'm 79/80 on that badge. However, just to the right under the Impact section it lists that i have 85 edited posts.

So why does the system say 79 edits in one location, and 85 in another?

Comment: Does it take into account duplicate edits? Meaning, you edit the same post twice ?

Comment: Related : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84766/strunk-white-badge-missing

Comment: Also see [Why haven't I received the Strunk & White badge?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266137)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that:

Few of the posts you edited might have been removed.

You edited total 85 posts and 6 of them might have been removed. (Deleted posts do not count towards 'strunk and white' badge).

OR

You edited single post twice.

Each edited post counts only once to award 'strunk and white' badge, regardless of how many additional edits you submit.

OR

There are few posts where you edited just the tags below question- are not taken into account to award 'strunk and white' badge.

Comment: Edits to post you own aren't counted towards the badge, also.

Comment: Yes buddy :)
You are right.
Are edited own posts also shown on new profile summary?- where it shows total edited posts count..
Am not sure on this :)
If it is confirmed then I shall add to my post :)

Comment: @Avidan Braiam is correct.  Plus if you want something official other than my word - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266137/why-havent-i-received-the-strunk-white-badge.

Comment: Worth note on that "edits to your own post" part- I checked and the spot the OP was talking about _already_ doesn't count edits to your own posts. I verified this by checking my own edits- I have 26 suggested edits, 1 conflict-rejected, and my "edited posts" counter in the upper right box shows "25 edited posts" instead of 46 like my "revisions" section in my activity page. So while they don't count towards the badge, they also aren't counted in the counter the OP is asking about.