# Understated values in next badge area

Tags: bug, badges

I still see other value of edited posts in next badge area than in impact area. I thought I have to wait to update first value, but when I had edited some post, both values increased immediately. Also I just waited, but first value is still smaller (always different is two). Screen:

[image]

Comment: You've probably edited two posts that have been deleted, or caching. One of the two.

Comment: There are a number of things that can affect this. See [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290331/2607247) for more of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your profile, you have suggested 65 edit.

In all of them you have 6 edit rejected and 59 approved from moderator.

Now the problem you have that it is showing 57 edit in your badge.

Reason:

In the area of **IMPACT** it shows all approved edit either the post has been deleted or not. But for the badge edit count is excluding the deleted post.

So badge count can vary from the **IMPACT** are count.

One of the deleted post that you have edit is here:

[Edited post that has been deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22083627/instantiate-pair-object-in-c/22083773#22083773)

Comment: I'm sure that this post didn't count into my edit status, but I see the point. In my reputation history, I have lot of `-2 removed [...]`. In fact, much more than two. I'm guessing that different equal to two is fault of other rule in counting edits. However, thank you for your explanation.

Comment: @Tacet you can also see this in all action tab's suggestion tab ... here is full list of suggested and approved and rejected suggestion.

Comment: @CodeLღver are you sure that's the reason? I have 93 edits in my "impact" and 90 in my "next badge", but I'm pretty sure I've edited more than 3 posts which were later deleted. I can find at least 7 of them checking my reputation changes...

Comment: @AJPerez don't check in the reputation tab, as -2 can be for downvote. If you want to check the all suggestion by you then click on *all action* tab and then click on *suggestion* . there will be full list of post that was edited by you.

Comment: True, but if you expand the rep. change for a given day, you can see what caused it. I'm counting only the ones with -2 which state "post was removed". The suggestions tab shows 96 edits, 3 were rejected, so I guess 93 is the correct number, given that this tab doesn't appear to show removed edits.

Comment: This answer is not 100% accurate. Removed posts aren't the only reason the two numbers might be different. See [this Meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290331/2607247) for other reasons why the numbers might not be the same.