# Strunk & White badge description not consistent with the Copy Editor badge

Tags: discussion, badges

Yesterday I asked myself, [as](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253691/strunk-white-badge-didnt-received?s=1%7C3.6427) [many](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266137/why-havent-i-received-the-strunk-white-badge?s=2%7C3.0254) [others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266137/why-havent-i-received-the-strunk-white-badge/266138#266138) [did](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253691/strunk-white-badge-didnt-received/253696#253696), why I didn't receive the Strunk & White badge. By searching over meta I found out why but it could have been less confusing if the reason would have been stated in the badge description.

What I don't understand is the reason why the gold  editor badge ([Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/223/copy-editor)) state it clearly:

> Edit 500 posts (excluding own or deleted posts and tag edits).

But [the silver badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) didn't:

> Edit 80 posts.

Though it seems both badges are calculated in the same way, as I have same advancement on both.

Is there any reason why this is different?

Comment: On Chess Meta, I have the [Editor badge](http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/users/7297/glorfindel?tab=profile), even though I only edited my own post there.

Comment: The full description (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732) seems to be inconsistent too, because own or deleted posts and tag edits are only under Copy Editor badge  but also count for Strunk & White badge.

Comment: IIRC, this has come up on Meta before, not this particular badge but about badge descriptions being incomplete.

Comment: @achecopar It seems that it's on a separate list, but the separation isn't clear. We could understand that the second list is related to the whole editor section, but only if you notice the 7px margin after the Copy Editor list :)

Comment: @vard Sorry I just checked it again and I had edited my own question, not really a post. I have just deleted my comment :p

Comment: @achecopar I noticed :) Would have been weird if the bronze badge wasn't calculated the same way as the silver/golden one.

Comment: @achecopar You do realize a question is a post, right? Because your comments read like questions are _not_ a form of post.

Comment: The bronze badge does not have any criteria past only editing the tags. It exists to teach users about the edit feature, whether it be on their own post or not. (PS, a question *is* a post.) As well, talking about deleted posts on a badge that only counts to one is kind of pointless.

Comment: @animuson I see. Though for the silver badge shouldn't the description reflect the real calculation, as it is for the gold badge?

Comment: animuson has already edited the full descriptions to emphasize general additional criteria. Thanks!